# quicktime long load times leaves blank area before loading

Tags: jquery, streaming, quicktime

I have an embedded quicktime video on my website, but it as it loads it leaves the area blank for 2-10 seconds. The alternative would be to convert to .flv and use a flash player, but I want this method to work.

Is there a way to have jpg placeholder or something as the quicktime loads, then switch it using jquery? It's just annoying.

Comment: Background image to the containing element?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you have enabled quick start in Quicktime movie. Otherwise you will need to collect all of the video or audio data (whichever is saved first in the file) before it will show anything.

you can look at quicktime streaming server also, in which case you will need to enable hinting as well.